# Android use Dropbox Api java.lang.VerifyError: com/dropbox/client2/RESTUtility

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox SDK to download a file saved in dropbox. I use this method inside an AsynTask:

```
@Override
public void downloadData() {
    String filePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/routes.xlsx";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("routes.xlsx", null, outputStream, null);
        Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev);
        RemoteResourcesLogic remoteResourcesLogic = new RemoteResourcesLogic();
        remoteResourcesLogic.read(filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("DbExampleLog", "Error getting folder");
    }

}
```

The problem is exactly in: DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("routes.xlsx", null, outputStream, null);

I have all neccessary .jar in libs folder:

- httpcore-4.0.1.jar
- junit-4.10.jar
- json_simple-1.1.jar
- httpmime-4.0.3.jar
- httpclient-4.0.3.jar
- dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar
- bcprov-jdk16-146.jar

And two jars to read xslx files:

- aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar
- aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5.jar

Can somebody help me?

Regards

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: com.curiocity.android, PID: 28885
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/dropbox/client2/RESTUtility

at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFileStream(DropboxAPI.java:1544)
at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFile(DropboxAPI.java:1497)
at com.curiocity.admin.ImportRoutesActivity.downloadData(ImportRoutesActivity.java:111)
at com.curiocity.admin.ImportRoutesActivity$DownloadData.doInBackground(ImportRoutesActivity.java:125)
at com.curiocity.admin.ImportRoutesActivity$DownloadData.doInBackground(ImportRoutesActivity.java:121)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/VerifyError.html) a `VerifyError` indicates:

> Thrown when the VM notices that an attempt is made to load a class which does not pass the class verification phase.

In the past, I've seen this when a library, e.g., json_simple-1.1.jar, wasn't added properly. Can you double check you've installed dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar and json_simple-1.1.jar properly? The instructions can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android

If you're using Android Studio, make sure you click "Add as library" for both.

Also, note that file paths for the Dropbox API should start with a `"/"`, so this line:

`DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("routes.xlsx", null, outputStream, null);`

should be:

`DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("/routes.xlsx", null, outputStream, null);`

Comment: Thanks Greg. I have added "/" to mDBApi.getFile("routes.xlsx", null, outputStream, null); In Android Studio I switch to Project view and I can see the libs folder and I can not see the "Add as library" options to json_simple-1.1.jar and dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar. Can you help me please? Regards

Comment: If the "Add as library" option isn't there, you likely already have it done. Perhaps try removing and re-adding the jars?